# C program fopen() does not open a file

Tags: c, fopen

I understand, there are thousands of problems like this, but I haven't managed to find the solution to my issue. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
FILE *inputFile=fopen("I:\\Test\main.cpp","R");
FILE *outFile=fopen("I:\\Test\main2.cpp", "W");
if (inputFile==NULL) {
    printf("Unable to locate source file");
    _getch();
    return 1;
}
int c;
int inSingleLine=0;
int inMultiLine=0;
int d=fgetc(inputFile);
while(c=fgetc(inputFile)!=EOF){
if (d==EOF) break;
if((c=='/') && (d=='*')) inMultiLine=1;
if ((c='*') && (d=='/')) inMultiLine=0;
if((c=='/')&& (d=='/')) inSingleLine=1;
if (c='\n') inSingleLine=0;
if (!inSingleLine && !inMultiLine) {
    putc(c,outFile);
}
d=getc(inputFile);
}
// This is a test string
fclose(inputFile);
fclose(outFile);

/* And this is not a test
Actually not
*/

return 0;
}
```

No matter what I do, whether I put main.cpp to the same folder with the exe file and make it `FILE *inputFile=fopen("main.cpp","R");` or specify an absolute path, I get "Unable to locate source file" all the time.
Please help!

Comment: `"I:\\Test\main.cpp"` --> `"I:\\Test\\main.cpp"` and `"R"` --> `"r"`

Comment: nope, still the same issue

Comment: @small-j have you tried `"r"` instead of `"R"`?

Comment: The same for `main2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mode strings for read and write mode are `"r"` and `"w"`, not `"R"` and `"W"`. Using an invalid mode is probably what's causing `fopen` to fail.

Comment: Exactly, why would someone use `"R"`?

Comment: @iharob It's a first letter in a sentence :)

Comment: And a follow-up to this... looking at error codes is helpful!

Answer (score 3):

```
int main()
{
FILE *inputFile=fopen("I:\\Test\main.cpp","R"); <-- This results in the string "I:\Testain.cpp"
  ...
```

Make sure you use two "\" symbols (escape both back-slashes), and use lower-case "w" and "r":

```
FILE *inputFile=fopen("I:\\Test\\main.cpp","r");
```

Answer (score 0):

As above, you must "escape" a backslash with a double one. You should **always** check the return value from `fopen()` and then you can obtain a message based on `errno`. When I tried the following with a lower-case `"r"` I got a compiler warning about the invalid escape sequence `\m` but the program was well behaved.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *inputFile=fopen("I:\\Test\main.cpp","r");
    printf("After trying to open\n");
    if (inputFile == NULL)
        printf ("%s\n", strerror(errno));
    else
        fclose(inputFile);
    return 0;
}
```

I got:

```
After trying to open
No such file or directory
```

But when I tried it with an upper-case `"R"` the program hung (MSVC), I don't know why.